# Performing action a button click event, button being placed inside dojox.grid.DataGrid.

Tags: javascript, jsp, button, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have a `dojox.grid.DataGrid`. In this a set of values are being displayed along with last 2 columns being filled up with `buttons` which are created dynamically according to data being retrieved from database using `formatter` property in `gridStruture`. Now i am getting the my grid fine. Buttons are also coming up fine. What i need to do now is when i click on a particular button on that button click event i redirect it to a new URL with a particular value(A) being passes as a query string parameter in that URL. And i don't want my page to be refreshed. Its like when a button is clicked it performs action on some other JSP page and displays message `alert("Action is being performed")`.

My java script code where i have coded for my data grid ::

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getInfoFromServer(){
        $.get("http://localhost:8080/2_8_2012/jsp/GetJson.jsp?random=" + new Date().getTime(), function (result) {
        success:postToPage(result),
        alert('Load was performed.');
            },"json");
    }


    function postToPage(data){
    alert(data);    
    var storedata = {
        identifier:"ActID",
        items: data
        };
    alert(storedata);

    var store1 = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data: storedata}) ;
    var gridStructure =[[

                          { field: "ActID",
                                name: "Activity ID",

                                classes:"firstName"
                          },
                          {
                              field: "Assigned To",
                              name: "Assigned To",

                              classes: "firstName"
                          },
                          { field: "Activity Type",
                                name: "Activity Type",

                                classes:"firstName"
                          },
                          {
                              field: "Status",
                              name: "Status",

                              classes: "firstName"
                          },
                          {
                              field: "Assigned Date",
                              name: "Assigned Date",

                              classes: "firstName"
                          },
                          {
                              field: "Assigned Time",
                              name: "Assigned Time",

                              classes: "firstName"
                          },
                          {
                              field: "Email",
                              name: "Send Mail",
                              formatter: sendmail,
                              classes: "firstName"

                          },
                          {
                              field: "ActID",
                              name: "Delete",
                              formatter: deleteact,
                                classes: "firstName"
                          }

                    ]
              ];
    //var grid = dijit.byId("gridDiv");
    //grid.setStore(store1);

    var grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({

        store: store1,
        structure: gridStructure,
        rowSelector: '30px',
        selectionMode: "single",
        autoHeight:true,
        columnReordering:true

        },'gridDiv');

    grid.startup();
    dojo.connect(grid, "onRowClick", grid, function(){
                var items = grid.selection.getSelected();
                dojo.forEach(items, function(item){
                    var v = grid.store.getValue(item, "ActID");
                    getdetailsfordialog(v);

                    function showDialog() {
                        dojo.require('dijit.Tooltip');
                        dijit.byId("terms").show();
                    }

                    showDialog();
                    }, grid);

            });
}

function sendmail(item) {
    alert(item);
      return "<button onclick=http://localhost:8080/2_8_2012/jsp/SendMailReminder.jsp?Send Mail="+item+"'\">Send Mail</button>";

    }
function deleteact(item) {
    alert(item);
      return "<button onclick=http://localhost:8080/2_8_2012/jsp/DeleteActivity.jsp?Activity ID="+item+"'\">Delete</button>";
    }
</script>
```

I am getting grid data using `$.get` call. In the above code field `Email` and `ActID` are actually buttons being created when each time function `sendmail` and `deleteact` are being called up in `formatter`. Grid is displayed. Also the value of `alert(item)` in both functions are coming up right that is there respective values. Like for `alert(item)` in `Delete` i am getting `ActID` and `alert(item)` in `sendmail` getting `"shan@gmail.com"` Now i want that on a particular `button click`(button in `Sendmail` column) my page

```
http://localhost:8080/2_8_2012/jsp/SendMailReminder.jsp?Send Mail="+item+"'
```

and `button click` in `Delete` column this page

```
http://localhost:8080/2_8_2012/jsp/DeleteActivity.jsp?Activity ID="+item+"'\"
```

opens up with value of items being retrieved from database. I have applied a `rowClick` event also which is also causing problem as when i click u button my `Rowclick` event fires instead of button click event.  How to do this. I thought of applying click event to each button on grid. But there ID i don't know. Please help me on this one. Thanks..

Comment: What do you mean by `performs action on some other JSP page`? Do you want to open this other JSP in popup window, or send ajax request to perform some server-side action or something else?

Comment: On that JSP SendMailReminder.jsp. I have an object of a class Send mail. This object calls a particular function of class that sends a mail to the value recived from item in query string. So basically i need to pass this value of item as a parameter to the called function in my SendMailReminder.jsp. Or what i can do is call that method on this same page only without redirecting it to SendMailReminder.jsp. If second one is possible please suggest me a way to do that ? Thanks

Comment: And Sir i keep on receiving an error "Tried to register an id="something" but that id is already registered" . I know its a pretty common error and gt something to do with removing the id from dojo registery or something. But i dnt understand clearly what it is. And how to overcome this. Thanks.. And i am not receving this error in my current page(Ques being asked). But keeps on getting it on some other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, what you need is adjusting your server-side code to handle ajax post requests for sending mail and use `dojo.xhrPost` method when user clicks button. Your JS code may look like this:

```
  function sendMailHandler(evt, item) {
    dojo.xhrPost({
      url: "/2_8_2012/jsp/SendMailReminder.jsp",
      content: {
        'SendMail': item
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("Sent failure");
      },
      load: function(result) {
        alert("Email sent with result: " + result);
      }
    });

    dojo.stopEvent(evt);
  }

  function sendmail(item) {
    return "<button onclick='sendMailHandler(arguments[0], \"" + item +  "\")'>Send Mail</button>";
  }
```

Note that `dojo.stopEvent(evt);` in `sendMailHandler` is used to stop event bubbling and prevents `RowClick` raising.

There is also `dojo.xhrGet` with similar syntax to perform ajax GET requests, which you can use instead of jQuery's `$.get`. You can also use `dojo.xhrGet` instead of `dojo.xhrPost` in my example, because there is chance that it will work with your back-end without tweaking, but `POST` (or ajax form submission) would be more semantically correct.

And about "Tried to register an id="something", you should adjust your code to avoid IDs duplication. Or show your code causing errors.

Comment: That worked fine, in the first attempt.. :) Thanks a lot sir.. Can u help me with this link also, New to dojo Getting probs.. Thanks again ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280815/refreshing-dojogrid