# Refreshing DojoGrid

Tags: javascript, ajax, datagrid, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have this grid which displays some data, that is retrieved from database. I am retrieving the data as a `JSON string` which comes in the form ::

```
[{"ActID":16,"Assigned To":"Anand","Activity Type":"fdsf","Status":"New","Assigned Date":"2012-04-20 00:00:00","Assigned Time":"1899-12-30 17:44:00","Email":"rakesh.shukla@gmail.com"},{"ActID":17,"Assigned To":"Anand","Activity Type":"fdsf","Status":"New","Assigned Date":"2012-04-20 00:00:00","Assigned Time":"1899-12-30 17:44:00","Email":"rakesh.shukla@gmail.com"}]
```

Let me put my code first ::

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getInfoFromServer(){
        $.get("http://anandkr08:8080/2_8_2012/jsp/GetJson.jsp?random=" + new Date().getTime(), function (result) {
        success:postToPage(result),
        alert('Load was performed.');
            },"json");
    }


    function postToPage(data){
    alert(data);    
    var storedata = {
        identifier:"ActID",
        items: data
        };
    alert(storedata);

    var store1 = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data: storedata}) ;
    var gridStructure =[[

                          { field: "ActID",
                                name: "Activity ID",
                                classes:"firstName"

                          },
                          {
                              field: "Assigned To",
                              name: "Assigned To",
                              classes: "firstName"

                          },
                          { field: "Activity Type",
                                name: "Activity Type",
                                classes:"firstName"

                          },
                          {
                              field: "Status",
                              name: "Status",
                              classes: "firstName"

                          },
                          {
                              field: "Assigned Date",
                              name: "Assigned Date",
                              classes: "firstName"

                          },
                          {
                              field: "Assigned Time",
                              name: "Assigned Time",
                              classes: "firstName"

                          },
                          {
                              field: "Email",
                              name: "SendMail",
                              formatter: sendmail,
                              classes: "firstName"

                          },
                          {
                              field: "ActID",
                              name: "Delete",
                              formatter: deleteact,
                              classes: "firstName"
                          }

                    ]
              ];
    //var grid = dijit.byId("gridDiv");
    //grid.setStore(store1);

    var grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({

        store: store1,
        structure: gridStructure,
        rowSelector: '30px',
        selectionMode: "single",
        autoHeight:true,
        columnReordering:true

        },'gridDiv');

    grid.startup();
    dojo.connect(grid, "onRowClick", grid, function(){
                var items = grid.selection.getSelected();
                dojo.forEach(items, function(item){

                    var v = grid.store.getValue(item, "ActID");
                    getdetailsfordialog(v);
                    function showDialog(){
                        dojo.require('dijit.Tooltip');
                        dijit.byId("terms").show();
                    }

                    showDialog();
                    }, grid);

            });
}
</script>
```

HTML code ::

```
<button id="pendingbutton" type="button" style="height: 50px; width: 100px;" onclick="getInfoFromServer()" value="Get Activities">Get Activities</button></center><br><br><br>
<center><div id="gridDiv"  title="Simple Grid">
</div></center>
```

Now in the above code `$.get` is called on click of a button (HTML code given above)an data is retrieved from database and grid is displayed for the first time on the page without refreshing the page(as it is called using $.get). Now what i want is when i click the button again. A new data is retrieved( which is working fine, have checked it from `alert(data)`) but grid is not refreshing itself. I want to refresh the grid without page refreshing. I have tried using `setstore`(commented out) function but it ain't working for me. Though when i click on a button to get a new data i do get the `error` in javascript console of google chrome that ::

```
Tried to register widget with id==gridDiv but that id is already registered
```

I think its gotta do something with assigning a new id every time a button is clicked. please help me out with the problem. Thanks.

The edited part ::

```
function initGrid(){
    var gridStructure =[[

                          { field: "ActID",
                                name: "Activity ID",
                                classes:"firstName"

                          },
                          {
                              field: "Assigned To",
                              name: "Assigned To",
                              classes: "firstName"

                          },
                          { field: "Activity Type",
                                name: "Activity Type",
                                classes:"firstName"

                          },
                          {
                              field: "Status",
                              name: "Status",
                              classes: "firstName"

                          },
                          {
                              field: "Assigned Date",
                              name: "Assigned Date",
                              classes: "firstName"

                          },
                          {
                              field: "Assigned Time",
                              name: "Assigned Time",
                              classes: "firstName"

                          },
                          {
                              field: "Email",
                              name: "SendMail",
                              formatter: sendmail,
                              classes: "firstName"

                          },
                          {
                              field: "ActID",
                              name: "Delete",
                              formatter: deleteact,
                              classes: "firstName"
                          }

                    ]
              ];

dojo.ready(function(){
    initGrid();
  });
```

My postToPage function ::

```
function postToPage(data){
    alert(data);    
    var storedata = {
        identifier:"ActID",
        items: data
        };
    alert(storedata);

    var store1 = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data: storedata}) ;
        grid = dijit.registry.byId("gridDiv");
        grid.set("store", store1);
        grid.filter();
        dojo.connect(grid, "onRowClick", grid, function(){
                var items = grid.selection.getSelected();
                dojo.forEach(items, function(item){

                    var v = grid.store.getValue(item, "ActID");
                    getdetailsfordialog(v);
                    function showDialog(){
                        dojo.require('dijit.Tooltip');
                        dijit.byId("terms").show();
                    }

                    showDialog();
                    }, grid);

            });
}
```

Here i am getting `error` ::

```
Cannot call method 'set' of undefined.
```

I think i have not defined my grid to be a `dojogrid.` Like this ::

```
var grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid
```

Can u please elaborate what else i need to write in my `initgrid()` function. Do i need to make any changes in my HTML code. I have defined structure but not assigned the structure. One more i have more than one dojogrid on same page. But my `initgrid` function is only one, containing only one structure. what changes i need to made so as i will be able to display other grids also ? My other grid are having different structure and each is represented by an ID in `<div>` element. Like above having an ID `"gridDiv"`. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this error because you are trying to create new grid widget each time button is clicked. There are 2 possible solutions: manually destroy existing widget, or create only one instance of grid widget and reuse it.

I think, you don't need to recreate your grid every time data is received from the server. I suggest you to move all your grid initialization logic (including structure, but except store assignment) into new method like `initGrid`, that will create empty grid. And call it one page load:

```
  dojo.ready(function() {
    initGrid();
  });
```

Then, when data received from the server, you can initialize data store and update grid (adjust your `postToPage` function):

```
  function postToPage(data){
    var storedata = {
      identifier:"ActID",
      items: data
    };
    var store1 = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data: storedata}) ;
    var grid = dijit.registry.byId("gridDiv");
    grid.set("store", store1);
    grid.filter();
  }
```

This should work. Also I suggest you not to use inline CSS styles and `center` tag.

**Update:**

You don't need to connect to `onRowClick` event each time data is updated, so it should be done in `initGrid` too.

Your `initGrid` method should look like this:

```
  function initGrid() {
    var gridStructure =[[
    // declare your structure here
    ]];

    var grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
      structure: gridStructure,
      rowSelector: '30px',
      selectionMode: "single",
      autoHeight:true,
      columnReordering:true
    },'gridDiv');


    dojo.connect(grid, "onRowClick", grid, function(){
      // onRowClick handler
    });

    grid.startup();
  }
```

Comment: Sir, thanks a ton for the reply, but things are not working fine as of now. Some changes need to be made. Please help me on that . really need that. I have edited the code. See for "The edited part:: ". thanks.

Comment: Updated my answer. By the way, dojo.ready should not be inside any function, in your code it seems it is inside initGrid function.

Comment: It worked sir.. :) Thanks a ton for your help.. u really helped me out... :) By the way i made a small change , used grid.setstore(store1).. The way u told me was not catching data that way.. anyways, thanks again.. Will surely ping you in future for my Dojo related problems.. :)

Comment: Sir need help on these links .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352841/entering-time-in-dijit-form-datetextbox

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353377/autocomplete-with-chrome-not-working-fine

Comment: Sir can u help me with this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512648/value-not-getting-selected-from-an-autocomplete-on-mouse-button-click