# Value not getting selected from an Autocomplete on Mouse button click

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, dojo, jquery-autocomplete, buttonclick

I have a `Jquery Autocomplete`. Its working fine. Values are selected when i move up and down from keyboard arrow key or hover a mouse on a particular value. But when i press button to put my selected value inside text box it doesn't work, instead if i press enter on keyboard the value is inputted in text box.

Let me give me my `code` for auto complete ::

```
$(document).ready(function hello(){
var myVar2 = <%=request.getAttribute("variable1")%>
      $("input#assignedtoid").autocomplete({
  source: myVar2
 });
});

<input dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" id="assignedtoid" name="assignedtoname"  required="true" onfocus="hello()" value=<%=session.getAttribute("Username")%> onblur="valassignedtoid()">
```

In above code `myVar2` is my data in `Json` form that is assigned a source for autocomplete. Values coming fine in autocomplete. `OnFocus` event in `input tag` i call `hello()` function. Why it is that value is not getting selected on `mouse button click`. However the site from where i picked up the code. the value is getting selected on Mouse click as well as on enter pressing. The `site` is ::

```
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/
```

Here the only diff is that there Source is static i am getting it from database in the form of `Json` thru `myVar2`. I am using IE. Using `dijit.form.ValidationTextBox` as my `input`

Please help. Thanks ..

The Edited Part ::

i have Imported The following js files::

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

And when i run it in `Google chrome` i don't get any auto complete. I do get an `error` that ::

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
```

is not found. And indeed its not valid anymore. But my auto complete works great when i run it on IE. Can this be the reason ? Also can u tell me which Jquery imports from the above i should delete if any of them is extra. Kinda confused.

i have taken the code from here ::

```
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `onfocus="hello()"` from your markup, and fix javascript:

```
dojo.require("dijit.form.ValidationTextBox");

dojo.ready(function () {
  var myVar2 = <%=request.getAttribute("variable1")%>;
  $("input#assignedtoid").autocomplete({
    source: myVar2
  });
});
```

BTW, Why don't you want to use `dijit.form.ComboBox` for pure dojo solution?

**UPDATE**

If you want to use google cdn, you need these imports:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.19/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.19/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Sir i have already done dojo.require("dijit.form.ValidationTextbox"); And ya changed my code to dojo.ready but things not working fine for me. Can there be any other prob ?

Comment: Have you removed `onfocus="hello()"` from your markup? Do see any JS errors in javascript console?

Comment: I have removed onfocus = "hello()" from my markup. Sir, i have edited my code. if this can help. See for the Edited part :: Thanks ..

Comment: Yes, autocomplete is part of jQuery UI

Comment: Sir can u help me on this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793551/making-dijit-dialog-transparent-when-it-shows-up