# Making dijit.Dialog Transparent when it shows up 

Tags: html, css, dojo

I have a `Dojo Dialog box` using `dijit.Dialog` library. It shows up on a `Rowclick` event of a `Dojo grid`. Now when it shows up I want it to be Transparent or reduce its opacity so that Whatever was in my background i can see it and it will look good. My Dialog box is a simple `<div> with data-dojo-type="dijit.Dialog"`.

The code is ::

```
<div id="terms" name ="hi" data-dojo-type="dijit.Dialog" style="height:580px;width:900px;" data-dojo-props="title:'Control Activities'" preload="true">
<center><p><strong>EDIT AN ACTIVITY </strong></p></center>
<center><table>
<tr style="height: 50px">
<td style="width: 150px" align="right"><b>ASSIGNED BY : &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</b></td>
<td style="width: 600px" align="left"><div id="plets"><input dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" id="dassignedbyid" name="dassignedbyname"  onfocus="hello()" required="true"></div>
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="dassignedbyid">Enter Name</span></td>
<td style="width: 150px" align="right"><b>ASSIGNED TO : &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</b></td>
<td style="width: 600px" align="left"><div id="plets1"><input dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" id="dassignedtoid" name="dassignedtoname" onfocus="hello()" required="true"></div>
<span dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="dassignedtoid">Enter Name</span></td></tr>
</table></center>
</div>
```

And the `Dialog box id= terms` shows up on this code ::

```
dojo.connect(grid, "onRowClick", grid, function(){
        var items = grid.selection.getSelected();
        dojo.forEach(items, function(item){

            var v = grid.store.getValue(item, "ActID");
            getdetailsfordialog(v);
            function showDialog(){
                dojo.require('dijit.Tooltip');
                dijit.byId("terms").show();
                document.getElementById('closelabelspan').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('holdlabelspan').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('startlabelspan').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('cancellabelspan').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('updatelabelspan').style.display = 'none';
            }

            showDialog();
            }, grid);
      });
```

Now i want that when this `dialog box(terms)` pops up it is transparent. I have tried one CSS also but that ain't working for me ::

```
<style>
div.transbox
  {
  width:900px;
  height:580px;
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  border:2px solid black;
  opacity:0.6;
  filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */

  }
</style>
```

I am using IE8.

How to do this ? Thanks ..

Function `showDialog()` edited ::

```
function showDialog(){
                dojo.require('dijit.Tooltip');
                dijit.byId("terms").on("show", function() { dojo.style(this.domNode, "opacity", 0.3); });
                dijit.byId("terms").show();
                document.getElementById('closelabelspan').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('holdlabelspan').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('startlabelspan').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('cancellabelspan').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('updatelabelspan').style.display = 'none';
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programatically

```
    var dia = new dijit.Dialog({
        title: "Click me!",
        onShow: function() {
            var me = this;
            // show routine sets opacity to 1, wait till it has and reset
            // second style call sets the underlay as well
            setTimeout(function() {
                dojo.style(me.domNode, "opacity", 0.4);
                dojo.style(dojo.byId(me.underlayAttrs.dialogId + me.underlayAttrs["class"]), "opacity", 0.4);
            }, 1000);
        },
        content: 'simple contents'
    });
    dia.startup();
    dia.show();
```

Via markup;

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.Dialog" style="height:580px;width:900px;" 
   data-dojo-props="title:'Control Activities'" preload="true">

   <script type="dojo/method" data-dojo-event="onShow" data-dojo-args="">
            var me = this;
            // show routine sets opacity to 1, wait till it has and reset
            // second style call sets the underlay as well
            setTimeout(function() {
                dojo.style(me.domNode, "opacity", 0.4);
                dojo.style(dojo.byId(me.underlayAttrs.dialogId + me.underlayAttrs["class"]), "opacity", 0.4);
            }, 1000);
   </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank a lot @mschr for your reply. But i ain't getting that opacity right. Though there's no error in the code. But my dialog box when shows up I get a simple white background no transparency . Have tried it in Chrome and IE8. I have edited my code above. See if i have edited it right. Thanks

Comment: re check answer, your edit is slightly off since it will attach a listener every time showDialog is called, thus ending up with X calls to dojo.style in the end. Instead put the onShow implementation where you construct it, ive shown markup variant for it as well as programmatic ways

Comment: 1) Open your developer toolbar; 2) click 'Inspect Element' 3) click on the dialog upper left corner. 3) hover elements in the hierachy (normally you would go as 'high' as containerNode) and find which node you wish to set background.. This node will have a CSS class - go to your stylesheet and set the background-color for that particular class.

Answer (score 0):

dijit dialog css style file  has: .dijitDialogUnderlay
Change the "backgounrd-color" property as :   background-color: #0000;